# Pausar a execução em um Service em Android

Tags: android, android-service

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Android onde há um `IntentService` para ler um arquivo.

Cada linha do arquivo representa um registro que deve possui um formato específico de acordo com os requisitos da aplicação. Um registro é inválido, por exemplo, se o numero de caracteres for maior que um determinado tamanho.

Preciso que, se durante a leitura do arquvio for encontrado algum registro inválido, a execução seja pausada e seja exibida uma notificação para perguntar se ele deseja pular aquela linha e continuar a leitura a partir da próxima linha ou se deseja cancelar toda a leitura.

> **Minha única dúvida é**: Como posso **pausar** a execução do código dentro de um `while` no método `protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` em um `IntentService`  para exibir a notificação, se isso for possível?

**Código de exemplo:**

```java
public class ImportImovelService extends IntentService {

    {...}

    // Será chamado assincronamente pelo Android
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null)
            return;

            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, FileUtil.ENCODE));

            String strLine;
            boolean eof = false;

            do {

                if ((strLine = br.readLine()) == null) {
                        // End of file (eof)
                        eof = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (strLine.length() > 136) {

                        // foi encontrado um registro inválido, deve pausar a
                        // leitura do arquivo e perguntar ao usuário se deve 
                        // continuar a leitura do arquivo.
                        // O usuário seleciona se continua ou se encerra a 
                        // leitura

                        if (usuarioEscolheContinuar) {
                            // pula o registro, cancela a iteração atual e
                            // prossegue para a próxima iteração
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            // a execução inteira é cancelada
                            stopForeground(true);
                            stopSelf();
                            return;                         
                        }

                    }


                // leitura normal do arquivo
                {...}                

            } while (!eof);

            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem!?

Talvez o [`CountDownTimer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) possa lhe ajudar.

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Crie uma contagem regressiva, e no caso do usuário der ok, vc poderá [cancelar a contagem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer#cancel()) regressiva e dar continuidade na sua instrução.